# What is the use/function of lithium chloride as an excipient in sofradex eardrops?

Tags: drugs, pharmacology

Certain drugs have lithium chloride as an excipient, eg. Caprilate, NeyDop N (Revitorgan-Dilutionen N Nr 97), NeyDop N (Revitorgan-Lingual Nr 97), Nisita.

An excipient is not supposed to have a pharmacological effect, but it seems like lithium chloride is an inhibitor of various enzymes (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15107743).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the main reason $\ce{LiCl}$ is used in liquid to soften ear wax is that [$\ce{LiCl}$ is quite hygroscopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_chloride) and pharmacologicically inactive under the conditions used (small amount used to retain moisture).

As you state, taken internally, in contact with the eyes, or *left in contact with skin for **extended** time*, [there are some biological effects](http://avogadro.chem.iastate.edu/MSDS/LiCl.htm), but I'd not be concerned about those with a tested commercial product.